# Why is there folders named "viber.old" on my windows 7 trash?

Tags: windows-7, viber

I checked my trash after 2 months and suddenly i found several (3) huge folders (128Mb, 228 Mb...) that i don't remember deleting and are all named "viber.old", inside there is a bunch of folders and a LOT of DLL files and a Viber.exe file.
Now i have viber for PC installed that i use very often.

I wonder where are they coming from and if they contain any of my messages as i really don't want to lose any of them.
Thank you

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps those are old installation files from previous updates.

Comment: I had the same guess, i just want an official viber link were i can read that viber put old versions in the TRASH and without the messages, or maybe its a virus